# Change LDIF suffix openLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I follow the instruction to install OpenLDAP server. Here's the tutorial :

> http://kukusan-network.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-setting-ldap-openldap-in-windows.html

Actually my case is I have an LDIF file. I want to import that LDIF to my LDAP server. So I decided to install the open LDAP. Then,
after I choose the BDB database. They will build the default suffix "maxcrc.com" .
If I make connection with this suffix, an error appears saying:

```
  [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge]
```

I think that error happened because my connection suffix is different from my LDIF suffix. So, how to change this default suffix? (to the suffix that I have in the LDIF file)

I already changed slapd.conf, but that wasn't a success.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is to go through the installation as is and then change the suffix in slapd.conf file. Then restart openldap and then check if the new suffix comes up when you connect to openldap. You can import your ldif file after this. I was able to get this to work with the same installer. This however never worked consistently for me.